# XSL transform failing and i can't see why

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Being a novice in writing XSL's i'm having issue debugging one for my current project. EditX-XML just fails the transform for errors but doesn't say where they are.

Any advise appreciated

Source XML:

```
<soa:Label xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core" identifier="ac7af7e5-a536-40ae-b7ca-93e62009c86a" name="Duration - Timecode to Frames" description="" instance="dc07adf4-79e4-4d33-b740-ece5bc0af991" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
<soa:Parameter type="timecode" identifier="82795f2a-5a2e-41ca-b1da-0c35a9c584e4" bindable="True" name="Duration Timecode" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">00:15:52:10@25
<soa:Default>00:00:00:00@29.97</soa:Default>
<soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
</soa:Parameter>
<soa:Parameter type="int32" identifier="ca643595-6cbb-46b4-bf9b-da93c4348a4e" bindable="True" name="Duration Frames" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">0
<soa:Default>0</soa:Default>
<soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
</soa:Parameter>
</soa:Label>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core" version="2.0">
<xsl:analyze-string select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]" regex="^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)@(\d+)$">
<xsl:matching-substring><xsl:variable name="hours" select="xs:integer(regex-group(1))"/>
<xsl:variable name="minutes" select="xs:integer(regex-group(2))"/>
<xsl:variable name="seconds" select="xs:integer(regex-group(3))"/>
<xsl:variable name="frames" select="xs:integer(regex-group(4))"/>
<xsl:variable name="fps" select="xs:integer(regex-group(5))"/>
<xsl:variable name="total-frames" select="$hours * 60 * 60 * $fps + $minutes * 60 * $fps + $seconds * $frames + $frames"/>
</xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
<xsl:template match="/">
<soa:Label identifier="5f01d03f-f867-4a57-92e0-19d239a3582d" name="Duration - Timecode to Frames pt2" description="" instance="dc07adf4-79e4-4d33-b740-ece5bc0af991" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core">
<soa:Parameter type="timecode" identifier="82795f2a-5a2e-41ca-b1da-0c35a9c584e4" bindable="True" name="Duration Timecode" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
<xsl:value-of select="/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]"/>
<soa:Default>00:00:00:00@29.97</soa:Default>
<soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
</soa:Parameter>
<soa:Parameter type="int32" identifier="ca643595-6cbb-46b4-bf9b-da93c4348a4e" bindable="True" name="Duration Frames" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1"><xsl:value-of select="$total-frames"/><soa:Default>0</soa:Default>
<soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
</soa:Parameter>
</soa:Label>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to test your XSLT at http://xsltransform.net/ you will see there are two errors with your XSLT

1. Element `xsl:analyze-string` is not allowed to be a child of
   `xsl:stylesheet`
2. You have defined a `total-frames` variable within
   this `xsl:analyze-string` but that means it is only in scope with
   the    `xsl:matching-substring` block, so cannot reference it else
   where.

See http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqj for specific details

What you need to do is move the `xsl:analyze-string` but also wrap the `xsl:variable` declaration of `total-frames` around it, so that the variable can then be used later on in the template.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <soa:Label identifier="5f01d03f-f867-4a57-92e0-19d239a3582d" name="Duration - Timecode to Frames pt2" description="" instance="dc07adf4-79e4-4d33-b740-ece5bc0af991" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
         <soa:Parameter type="timecode" identifier="82795f2a-5a2e-41ca-b1da-0c35a9c584e4" bindable="True" name="Duration Timecode" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]/text()[1])"/>
            <soa:Default>00:00:00:00@29.97</soa:Default>
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
         </soa:Parameter>

        <xsl:variable name="total-frames">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]/text()[1])"
                               regex="^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)@(\d+)$">
              <xsl:matching-substring>
                 <xsl:variable name="hours" select="xs:integer(regex-group(1))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="xs:integer(regex-group(2))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="xs:integer(regex-group(3))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="frames" select="xs:integer(regex-group(4))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="fps" select="xs:integer(regex-group(5))"/>

                 <xsl:value-of select="$hours * 60 * 60 * $fps + $minutes * 60 * $fps + $seconds * $frames + $frames"/>
              </xsl:matching-substring>
           </xsl:analyze-string>
       </xsl:variable> 

         <soa:Parameter type="int32" identifier="ca643595-6cbb-46b4-bf9b-da93c4348a4e" bindable="True" name="Duration Frames" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="$total-frames"/>
            <soa:Default>0</soa:Default>
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
         </soa:Parameter>
      </soa:Label>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note where you were selecting `soa:Parameter[1]` this would have included all line-breaks in the text too, and white-space nodes, so your regular expression would not have matched.

Having said that, it looks like you are are trying to do is append a text value to the second Parameter based on the first one. In that case, you may benefit from using the XSLT identity template.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="soa:Parameter[2]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]/text()[1])"
                               regex="^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)@(\d+)$">
              <xsl:matching-substring>
                 <xsl:variable name="hours" select="xs:integer(regex-group(1))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="xs:integer(regex-group(2))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="xs:integer(regex-group(3))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="frames" select="xs:integer(regex-group(4))"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="fps" select="xs:integer(regex-group(5))"/>

                 <xsl:value-of select="$hours * 60 * 60 * $fps + $minutes * 60 * $fps + $seconds * $frames + $frames"/>
              </xsl:matching-substring>
           </xsl:analyze-string>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @tim-c works a treat.

And thanks for the link to the validator site, very useful